# Vue + TypeScript - Recommended folder structure convention for placing custom typings?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, webpack, directory-structure

Is there a recommended convention in where to place your custom type definition files in a Vue project?

I've been using a folder named *./src/types* with this kind of tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "types"
    ]
  }
}
```

Somebody told me that Vue or Webpack would pick up files in *./@types/* folder automatically without needing to add this to *./tsconfig.json* - however, I did not find a reference to such information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to TypeScript website, TypeScript automatically loads types in folders if you have referenced them in your code.

[@types, typeRoots and types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

> By default all visible “@types” packages are included in your
>   compilation. Packages in node_modules/@types of any enclosing folder
>   are considered visible; specifically, that means packages within
>   ./node_modules/@types/, ../node_modules/@types/,
>   ../../node_modules/@types/, and so on.
>
> If typeRoots is specified, only packages under typeRoots will be
>   included. For example:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "typeRoots" : ["./typings"]
   }
}
```

> This config file will include all packages under ./typings, and no
>   packages from ./node_modules/@types

You can easily test it like:

```
tc --init
```

Create a `index.d.ts` file inside `@types/index.d.ts`, and put code below in it:

```
declare interface Foo {
    Bar: string;
}
```

In the root folder, create a new `index.ts` file and inside your code-editor (Eg. VSCode), test it:

```
let foo:Foo;
foo. // you can see code-completion
```

p.s:
It doesn't matter if you put your code inside @types or not, TypeScript automatically will find them. You can manually define the path for typeRoots as well but don't forget to configure it to looks for @types inside `node_modules`.